# Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): in C:\xampp\htdocs\engine\classes\bd.Class.php on line 4

Tags: php

I have a problem with my extends class for connections to mysqli. I dont understand how to exdend the mysqli's construct in my class Logare. Here I want to check the connection but It shows those errors.
My bd file is bd.Class.php

```
<?php
class ConectareBd{
    function __construct(){
        $bd = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
        $bd->set_charset("utf8");
        echo "xzxzxcxd";
    }
}
?>
```

logare.Class.php is

```
<?php
require_once('bd.class.php');
class Logare extends ConectareBd{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
?>
```

and index.php

```
<?php require_once('/engine/classes/logare.Class.php'); 
$Log = new Logare;
?>
```

How can I fix those errors from the index.php:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): in C:\xampp\htdocs\engine\classes\bd.Class.php on line 4

Warning: mysqli::set_charset(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\engine\classes\bd.Class.php on line 5
xzxzxcxd
```

Thank you!